# How to create a recursive interface with default

Tags: typescript, logic

For a project, I want to create a Typescript interface that has a generic that narrows down the types of the children.

```
interface Node<Type extends Node = Node> {
  children: Node<Type>[]
}
```

The compiler throws an error: [`Type parameter 'Type' has a circular default.(2716)`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHsAmEAqBPABwgB58jkIAPSETAZzS10JQF5HsyIA+ZAbwCwAKGTIEAC2AAbTFAggAXB2ZFSLbgG0AusIC+QA)

Does my requirement make sense or should it be solved differently?

Comment: You can't have `Node<Type extends Node = Node>` because the compiler will eagerly evaluate it to `Node<Type extends Node<Type extends Node<Type  ... >>>>`. That's why you get the `circular` error. You might want to use `Node<Type extends Node<any> = Node<any>>` but this way you can have anything inside `Node`. I don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: Okay, so my request makes sense, but would require modifications to the Typescript parser?